# Python (Numpy Array) - Flipping an image pixel-by-pixel

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

I have written a code to flip an image vertically pixel-by-pixel. However, the code makes the image being mirrored along the line x = height/2.

I have tried to correct the code by setting the range of "i" from (0, h) to (0, h//2) but the result is still the same.

[Original Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6wW0.png)   [Resulted Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYGoI.png)

```
#import libraries
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

#read image (set image as m)
m = Image.open('lena.bmp')

#change image to array (set array as np_array)
np_array = np.array(m)

#define the width(w) and height(h) of the image
h, w = np_array.shape

#make the image upside down
for i in range(0,h):
    for j in range(0,w):
        np_array[i,j] = np_array[h-1-i,j]
        
#change array back to image (set processed image as pil_image)
pil_image = Image.fromarray(np_array)

#open the processed image
pil_image.show()

#save the processed image
pil_image.save('upsidedown.bmp')
```

Comment: Your code does fine halfway down the image. But think about what the image looks like at that point. The top half of the image was overwritten with the mirrored bottom half. So when you try to overwrite the bottom half with the overwritten top half, you actually don't change the bottom. To do what you want, each iteration selects a pair of pixels to swap, extract the values to temporary variables, and overwrite the pixels with the swapped extracted values. NumPy already has a function `flip` for doing that along any axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above given code is replacing the image pixels inplace, that is why the result is a mirrored image.
If you want to flip the image pixel by pixel, just create a new array with same shape and then replace pixels in this new array. For example:

```
#import libraries
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

#read image (set image as m)
m = Image.open('A-Input-image_Q320.jpg')

#change image to array (set array as np_array)
np_array = np.array(m)
new_np_array = np.copy(np_array)

#define the width(w) and height(h) of the image
h, w = np_array.shape

#make the image upside down
for i in range(0,h):
    for j in range(0,w):
        new_np_array[i,j] = np_array[h-1-i,j]
        
#change array back to image (set processed image as pil_image)
pil_image = Image.fromarray(new_np_array)

#open the processed image
pil_image.show()

#save the processed image
pil_image.save('upsidedown.bmp')
```